# OpenStack Neutron outside communication through router doesn't work, local between VMs does

Tags: networking, openstack, routing, nova

I am pretty lost with this one for few day now and can't move further. Any ideas will be very welcome.
My private net for VMs: 10.5.5.0/24
Outside link via 192.168.22.0/24 (my router's IP 192.168.22.1)

```
 neutron subnet-list
+--------------------------------------+------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| id                                   | name | cidr            | allocation_pools                                     |
+--------------------------------------+------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| 7b77e45f-160f-4808-b710-f644045f8d19 |      | 192.168.22.0/24 | {"start": "192.168.22.130", "end": "192.168.22.135"} |
| b783a811-98f3-4fbe-bd2d-2f7b1378a000 |      | 10.5.5.0/24     | {"start": "10.5.5.2", "end": "10.5.5.254"}           |
+--------------------------------------+------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------+

neutron net-list
+--------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
| id                                   | name    | subnets                                              |
+--------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
| 5a523463-77e6-410e-92e2-cb191418e3c5 | net1    | b783a811-98f3-4fbe-bd2d-2f7b1378a000 10.5.5.0/24     |
| efaa5928-ddca-4dbc-88a0-80dd9a95e5b8 | ext_net | 7b77e45f-160f-4808-b710-f644045f8d19 192.168.22.0/24 |
+--------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+

nova list
+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
| ID                                   | Name         | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks                      |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
| 6a84c26c-47c4-4b03-9bd1-fa3abd2c9ad3 | CirrOS test1 | ACTIVE | None       | Running     | net1=10.5.5.2, 192.168.22.131 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------------------------+

neutron floatingip-list
+--------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| id                                   | fixed_ip_address | floating_ip_address | port_id                              |
+--------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 4fcaa953-4fac-4459-a27e-1c2349e8f3b4 | 10.5.5.2         | 192.168.22.131      | f0d72b97-a8fa-42f0-942f-83f623c83128 |
+--------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

I can successfully ping between VMs when there are multiple running in network
10.5.5.0/24, but all the other communication inside or outside doesn't work.

```
ovs-vsctl show
5d243164-aa3f-4323-aa64-64239b7f3ba2
    Bridge br-int
        Port "qg-85228b4f-4c"
            Interface "qg-85228b4f-4c"
                type: internal
        Port "em1"
            Interface "em1"
        Port "qr-88abb9f7-6d"
            Interface "qr-88abb9f7-6d"
                type: internal
        Port "tap9f56fceb-45"
            Interface "tap9f56fceb-45"
                type: internal
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
    Bridge br-ex
        Port "em2"
            Interface "em2"
        Port br-ex
            Interface br-ex
                type: internal
    ovs_version: "1.10.2"


ip netns list
qdhcp-5a523463-77e6-410e-92e2-cb191418e3c5
qrouter-67268e5b-89bc-4c79-b698-ca3b57912371


ip netns exec qrouter-67268e5b-89bc-4c79-b698-ca3b57912371 ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:130 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:130 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:12241 (12.2 KB)  TX bytes:12241 (12.2 KB)

qg-85228b4f-4c Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:ea:3e:ff
          inet addr:192.168.22.130  Bcast:192.168.22.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f816:3eff:feea:3eff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1338504 errors:0 dropped:1210 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:138 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:105453095 (105.4 MB)  TX bytes:15786 (15.7 KB)

qr-88abb9f7-6d Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:73:b1:ff
          inet addr:10.5.5.1  Bcast:10.5.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f816:3eff:fe73:b1ff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1338707 errors:0 dropped:1208 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:105590392 (105.5 MB)  TX bytes:1642 (1.6 KB)
```

/etc/nova/nova.conf content:

```
[DEFAULT]
neutron_metadata_proxy_shared_secret = pass
service_neutron_metadata_proxy = true
network_api_class=nova.network.neutronv2.api.API
neutron_url=htxp://Control:9696
neutron_auth_strategy=keystone
neutron_admin_tenant_name=service
neutron_admin_username=neutron
neutron_admin_password=pass
neutron_admin_auth_url=htxp://Control:35357/v2.0
linuxnet_interface_driver = nova.network.linux_net.LinuxOVSInterfaceDriver
firewall_driver=nova.virt.firewall.NoopFirewallDriver


dhcpbridge_flagfile=/etc/nova/nova.conf
dhcpbridge=/usr/bin/nova-dhcpbridge
logdir=/var/log/nova
state_path=/var/lib/nova
lock_path=/var/lock/nova
force_dhcp_release=True
iscsi_helper=tgtadm
libvirt_use_virtio_for_bridges=True
connection_type=libvirt
root_helper=sudo nova-rootwrap /etc/nova/rootwrap.conf
verbose=True
ec2_private_dns_show_ip=True
api_paste_config=/etc/nova/api-paste.ini
volumes_path=/var/lib/nova/volumes
enabled_apis=ec2,osapi_compute,metadata
my_ip=192.168.22.10
vncserver_listen=192.168.22.10
vncserver_proxyclient_address=192.168.22.10
auth_protocol = http
auth_strategy=keystone
rpc_backend = nova.rpc.impl_kombu
rabbit_host = Control
rabbit_password = pass
rabbit_port = 5672
rabbit_use_ssl=false
rabbit_userid=guest


[database]
connection = mysql://nova:pass@Control/nova
[keystone_authtoken]
auth_host = Control
auth_port = 35357
auth_protocol = http
admin_tenant_name = service
admin_user = nova
admin_password = adminpass
```

/etc/neutron/neutron.conf content:

```
[DEFAULT]

rabbit_host = Control
rabbit_password = 
rabbit_port = 5672
rabbit_use_ssl=false
rabbit_userid=guest
state_path = /var/lib/neutron

lock_path = $state_path/lock
core_plugin = neutron.plugins.openvswitch.ovs_neutron_plugin.OVSNeutronPluginV2
api_paste_config = /etc/neutron/api-paste.ini
auth_strategy = keystone


fake_rabbit = False
notification_driver = neutron.openstack.common.notifier.rpc_notifier

neutron.services.loadbalancer.agent_scheduler.ChanceScheduler


[quotas]

[agent]
root_helper = sudo /usr/bin/neutron-rootwrap /etc/neutron/rootwrap.conf

[keystone_authtoken]
auth_host = Control
admin_tenant_name = service
admin_user = neutron
admin_password = 
auth_port = 35357
auth_protocol = http

auth_strategy = keystone
signing_dir = $state_path/keystone-signing

rpc_backend = neutron.openstack.common.rpc.impl_kombu
rabbit_host = Control
rabbit_port = 5672
rabbit_password = 

[database]
connection = mysql://neutron:@Control/neutron

[service_providers]
service_provider=LOADBALANCER:Haproxy:neutron.services.loadbalancer.drivers.haproxy.plugin_driver.HaproxyOnHostPluginDriver:default
```

/etc/neutron/plugins/openvswitch/ovs_neutron_plugin.ini content:

```
[ovs]
tenant_network_type = vlan
network_vlan_ranges = physnet1:1100:2999
bridge_mappings = physnet1:br-int
[agent]

[securitygroup]
neutron.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.OVSHybridIptablesFirewallDriver
firewall_driver = nova.virt.firewall.NoopFirewallDriver
```

---

Any pointers into the right direction will be very appreciated, after pulling my hair because of this for last few days.

If you guys need any other information, I will be happy to post.

TIA, Matej

Comment: My system behaves the same way: internal comms works but external does not. Mine is the Icehouse version of OpenSTack installed in three Ubuntu 12.04 VMs under Oracle VirtualBox on a Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 system.

Answer (score 0):

br-int is the integration brige - i.e. VM facing.

In a OS VLAN networking config your physnet bridge mapping should be to the external interface that has the VLANs trunked to it.

This normally looks something like this:

bridge_mappings = physnet1:br-eth1